# LINQ Select Statement to Map Entity Using Recursion

Tags: c#, linq, recursion, select, parent-child

I have a `Category` Entity that has a collection of child Categories and a nullable reference to a `Parent Category`.

```
public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }

    public Category Parent { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Category> Children { get; set; } 
}
```

I have the scenario where I need to "copy" an existing entity (`Zone`) which has references to `Categories`. Within the select statement I need to map the existing categories and their children to a new Category record so that when I save the new categories will hold a reference to the new copied `Zone`.

The problem I'm having is a recursion method that will loop through the current LINQ select (`x`) Category and create new Category records for each of its children s children etc.

Here is the relevant part of the current "copy" select statement I have. Do I call `Where` on `Categories` that are top level i.e don't have a `ParentId` and then use a recursive method for the children?

```
Categories = zone.Categories.Where(y => !y.ParentId.HasValue).Select(x => new Category
{
     Children = WHAT DO I PUT IN HERE
     Name = x.Name,
}).ToList()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you perhaps looking for a copy constructor like this?

```
public class Category 
{
    // Copy constructor, recursively called for each child.
    public Category(Category other)
    {
        Id = other.Id;
        Name = other.Name;
        ParentId = other.ParentId;
        Parent = other.Parent;
        // Use this copy constructor for each child too:
        Children = other.Children.Select(c => new Category(c)).ToList();
    }
    // We probably want the default constructor too.
    public Category() { }

    // Your Props...
}
```

Usage:

```
var deepCopied = zone.Categories.Select(c => new Category(c));
```

Comment: I had already came up with a solution as this was posted. Its similar to what I have so I will make it as the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use a select recursive method like so:

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> SelectRecursive<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> selector)
    {
        foreach (var parent in source)
        {
            yield return parent;

            var children = selector(parent);
            foreach (var child in SelectRecursive(children, selector))
                yield return child;
        }
    }
}
```

Then do an implementation:

```
var lookup = _dbContext.Categories.ToLookup(x => x.ParentId);
var parents = lookup[null].SelectRecursive(x => lookup[x.Id]).Where(c => c.ParentId == null).ToList();
```

Comment: I've already read this solution on a different post and it doesn't meet the requirement I need.